# expose multiple ports in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I need to expose a range of ports in Amazon ECS.
the task definition limits single port mapping from host to container. like:

```
"portMappings": [
{
    "containerPort": 80,
    "hostPort": 80
},
  {
    "containerPort": 443,
    "hostPort": 443,
},
 {
    "containerPort": 0,
    "hostPort": 9080
}
],
```

and I did not find any solution to expose a range of ports like 32769-65535.
is there any way I can map the range of EC2 ports in the container?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [port mapping for AWS ECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65746517/port-mapping-for-aws-ecs)

Comment: @omuthu,
I can not use the "host" drive due to the autoscaling group and ports conflict
and in "awsvpc" mode, LB is in container level which is not usefule :/